# WPF - Context menu on a single item in a treeview?

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I am not very skilled (if at all) with WPF, and I am faced with the following problem. 
I have a treeview control (XAMtreeView) where I am binding a contextmenuitem on. Now, I want the contextmenu to only display for one of the 5 tree node items (e.g. right clicking on the 4th item should pop it on, but right click should do nothing for the other items). I tried using databinding but something tells me that is the wrong way to go - nevertheless, here is what I have so far:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryTreeNodeTemplate">
    <TextBlock Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=ScenarioOptions}" 
                               Text="{Binding Data.Name}" Style="{StaticResource ScreenNodeTitleStyle}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu Visibility="Hidden" cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <ContextMenu.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="ContextMenu">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource  Mode=FindAncestor,  AncestorType={x:Type TextBlock}}}" Value="CTS Charts">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContextMenu.Style>
                <MenuItem Header="{StaticResource ExternalChartOpenFile}" cal:Message.Attach="OpenExternalFile()">
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see I am trying to play with the visibility tag - and failing miserably while at it :). How do I make the context menu apply on a single treenode item?

Thanks :/

Comment: Can you tell us what it is about this one item that is different from the others? Why does this one need a context menu, and the others not?

Comment: Yes - it's the only one supposed to have a context menu. The other items aren't suppose to display one.

Comment: That does not explain why. The answer to why might help us find a solution for you.

Comment: Because, only one of my tree view items should have that particular functionality - none other should :)

Comment: Ok, that's cool. Good luck.